# Round float to the nearest quarter in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point

I'm working with an external api in a Ruby on Rails app. I need to send in floats to this company but they only accept values like `1.0`, `1.25`, `1.5`, `1.75`, `2.0`, etc.

I may have a value like `1.34` or `1.80`. I ideally need to round them to the nearest `0.25`. What's the best way to accomplish this? if I do `1.34.round(0)` it'll give me `1.0` which is lower than I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
(1.27 * 4).round / 4.0
#=> 1.25
```

If you're going to use it often, it would make perfect sense to monkey patch the `Float` class, to make the usage simpler:

```
class Float
  def round_to_quarter
    (self * 4).round / 4.0
  end
end
1.27.round_to_quarter
#=> 1.25
1.52.round_to_quarter
#=> 1.5
1.80.round_to_quarter
#=> 1.75
1.88.round_to_quarter
#=> 2.0
```

Comment: Its honestly a matter of opinion Dinesh

Answer (score -3):

While Andrey's solution will work if you are not comfortable with [monkey patching](http://culttt.com/2015/06/17/what-is-monkey-patching-in-ruby/) a primary ruby class the following will work as well

```
#x being the value
(x * 4).round / 4.0
```

Comment: It is *literally* the same as `(self * 4).round / 4.0` from my example having that `self` is an instance of Float :)

Comment: Yea I absolutely agree with you. Just an alternative. :)